# Adding figures using inkscape and

Tags: errors, diagrams, debugging

I was searching about how to add inkscape  diagrams to LaTeX file. And I found [this](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-2/) blog from a student who is using incscape and LaTeX for taking lecture notes. Coming to my issue: I loaded packages that he's showing

```
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{transparent}
\newcommand{\incfig}[1]{\def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}\import{#1.pdf_tex}}
```

But when I try to add figure with

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \incfig{drawing}
\end{figure}
```

it gives me an error, and `drawing` and my `.tex` file is in the same folder

```
l.49 \end
         {figure}
c:/Users/*path_to_file*/p1.tex:49: Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   def
```

And this same thing shows up 100 times and at the end `(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)` shows.
Additionally,

```
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'c:/Users/*path_to_file/p1.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

Please help me to fix this i don't know what to do, I could use some other methods for including inkscape file but i keep this as last solution if nothing helps.

Comment: Have you tried using `\input` instead of `\import` if the file is in the same directory?

Comment: it gives error too `File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.` and `Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: The best and simplest is save the diagram as foo.pdf  in Inkscape **without check omit the text and make a LaTeX file**,  and then use with  `\includegraphics{foo}`. Only if the fonts type and size of the diagram **must** match the font of the main text, check that option. This will produce `foo.pdf` and  `foo.pdf_tex` and then read carefully the comments of `foo.pdf_tex` about how and when use `\input` or `\import`.

Comment: Well, except guesswork there isn't much we can do for this question. Can you please provide your full log so we can have a look? Debugging with only snippets is impossible.

Comment: @Fran <script src="https://gist.github.com/spitfire-hash/4bb1d5e78445b85dc2fba094cdf8a496.js"></script> here's your suggestion's log file it gives error too. I did what comments say in the `.tex_pdf` file

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz <script src="https://gist.github.com/spitfire-hash/e6643e2a3ea024826ff21d5913cec13d.js"></script> here's not changed file's log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing really complicated. I just changed `\import` to `\input` and added `\usepackage{graphicx}` to preamble . The problem was `\input` is undefined control sequence without `graphicx` package. Thanks you all for help!

Comment: What  is undefined without the `graphicx` package is `\includegraphic, not `\input`. The problem with `\import` was that you must pass two mandatory argument to this command, i.e. ` \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}`  but you used `\import<MISSING ARGUMENT> {#1.pdf_tex}` that in the other hand, is not the right command if the  ` .pdf_tex` file is in the working directory.

Comment: It showed  `includegraphics` is undefined control sequence, but I didn't have that command on my file but I added `graphicx` and issue is gone